# How to retrieve a value from stdout of ansible registered variable?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

One of my ansible play is using a shell module to create a vault token.The command returns some value that I want to use in next play. 
I registered the command output in vault_output parameter.Here I am getting stdout from that variable.

```
    "vault_output.stdout": {
        "auth": {
            "accessor": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "client_token": "abcdefghijkl",
            "entity_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "lease_duration": 600,
            "metadata": {
                "username": "vault"
            },
            "policies": [
                "default",

            ],
            "renewable": true,
            "token_policies": [
                "default",

            ]
        },
        "data": {},
        "lease_duration": 0,
        "lease_id": "",
        "renewable": false,
        "request_id": "3470a160-3ed5-ceaa-f57b-4f3d74f6a269",
        "warnings": null,
        "wrap_info": null
    }
}
```

I am looking to get value of client_token which should be abcdefghijkl. Can anyone help me out to get that value which can be used in next play.

I have tried using vault_output.stdout[num], vault_output.stdout_lines, vault_output.stdout.auth , vault_output.stdout.['auth'] but no luck.

Expecting Result:
"client_token": "abcdefghijkl"

Comment: plz try `vault_output.stdout['auth']['client_token']`.

Comment: This did not work out :(

`vault_output.stdout['auth']['client_token']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!`

Comment: i dont know why, but registering the result of a `shell` task, doesnt give me a json like yours. you have some special fields like `auth`, `data`, `lease_duration` etc, that dont seem to come from a shell module. if you could add the code that led to this registered output, perhaps it would help

Comment: @Milind Dhoke; If you see "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" then something is wrong with your code. Either double-check the syntax or post the code.

Comment: @ilias-sp 
` - name: Generating Vault Auth Token 
    shell: |
      curl -sSfL  --request POST --data "{\"password\":\"{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}\"}" \
      https://vault-server:{{ vault_server_port }}/v1/auth/ldap/login/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}
    register: vault_output`

Comment: This command is going well and output is correct also. Only I wanted to get `client_token` value from returned stdout.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found an answer to this.

```
- set_fact:
    result: "{{ (vault_output.stdout | from_json).auth.client_token }}"

- debug: 
    var: result
```

`result: 9fa7fdd6-c8da-ac8c-b5d8-df18b17eb3f0`

Answer (score 0):

The output from `debug: var=vault_output.stdout` is actually a bit misleading here. The variable does not contain a dict object Ansible can index. You will need to first parse it with the `from_json` filter:

```
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ vault_output.stdout | from_json }}"

    - debug:
        var: result.auth.client_token
```

Comment: No luck with this solution as well. 

I got stdout in result variable but when calling result.auth.client_token, ansible error out as undefined variable.

Comment: Assigned value to result variable is as below: 
```
ok: [xyz.com] => {
    "result": " {u'lease_id': u'', u'warnings': None, u'wrap_info': None, u'auth': {u'token_policies': [u'default', u'sec-development'], u'entity_id': u'a31cbee0-aee2-f021-b908-42191dffc8f4', u'lease_duration': 600, u'policies': [u'default', u'sec-development'], u'client_token': u'eda50b75-529b-ecb9-9180-1beb1ea13f97', u'accessor': u'9191b082-c5f6-55c0-a759-c84be285ffe7', u'renewable': True,  u'request_id': u'40f65b3f-cc17-f090-444e-2a9dfab158af', u'data': {}, u'renewable': False}"
}
```

Comment: Also Error is 

`"result.auth.client_token": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'client_token'"`